# How to add search option in android spinner

Tags: android, search, spinner, android-spinner

I have an android application where I have to implement a spinner for showing currencies with search option.I have done it using SearchableSpinner but it have some limitation that took me to try some different options.The limitations that I faced with SearchableSpinner are as below.

1. Can't select an item at a particular position dynamically.
2. Can't search a currency with 2 strings in search field.That is, if i need to find 'United States Dollar' for that i can only type united or states or dollar and it will show the 'United States Dollar' as search result, but if i search 'United States' or something with 2 or more string it will not display any currency.

So how can I implement a searchable spinner by covering these limitations.Its not necessary to do this using a spinner,I just want the same feel of using a spinner .I hope everyone understood my question and please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look on AutocompleteTextview with dropdown adapter which give you ability to search in the given data.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: But if i choose AutoCompleteTextView then i think the dropdown  will show only if the user type a minimum of 1 letter in the textview.Am i right??

Comment: For that you can set a threshold limit after how many letter you want to open the dropdown.

Comment: I want to open the dropdown when i click on the textview.So i need to set zero as the threshold limit .but unfortunately its not posible.The minimum value of threshold limit is 1.

Comment: YourView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            autocomptv.showDropDown();
            autocomptv.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
    });

Comment: use above code, it works for me..Check if it work for you or not